# Not initialized PL/pgSQL constant: is it possible?

Tags: postgresql, constants, plpgsql

Is it possible to `DECLARE` a constant variable to be assigned (once and only once) later on in the body of a PL/pgSQL function?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS void AS 
$$
   DECLARE
      dummy CONSTANT text;
   BEGIN
      -- ...do stuff...
      dummy := 'now I know';
      -- ...do more stuff...
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I'm pretty sure it is not possible, indeed you would get:

> ```sql
> ERROR:  "dummy" is declared CONSTANT
> ```

but maybe there is some ongoing development, or some trick I am missing to somehow *turn* a variable to constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible *workaround*: use a [**subblock**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html):

```sql
DO $do$
<< main >>
DECLARE
   dummy CONSTANT text;  -- without assingment it's just NULL
   myvar text;
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'dummy is >>%<<', dummy;          -- <NULL>
   -- dummy := 'foo';    -- would raise exception!

   SELECT INTO myvar age FROM event.age limit 1;  -- some computation

   << subblock >>
   DECLARE
      dummy CONSTANT text := myvar; -- assign result of earlier computation
   BEGIN
      RAISE NOTICE 'dummy is now >>%<<', dummy;                       -- 'boom'
      RAISE NOTICE 'same with subblock.dummy: >>%<<', subblock.dummy; -- 'boom'
      RAISE NOTICE 'dummy in outer block is >>%<<', main.dummy;       -- <NULL>
   END;

   RAISE NOTICE 'dummy is >>%<< again', dummy;                        -- <NULL>
END
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

***Continue the subblock until the end of the function*** to simulate *exactly* what you were asking for.
Note that a subblock has a tiny cost overhead, so you would not use it unless you need it.

Aside: never quote <strike>'plpgsql'</strike>. It's an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

no, it is not possible. You can set value of constant only in DECLARATION part.

```
postgres=# do $$
postgres$# declare c constant text := 'Ahoj';
postgres$# begin
postgres$#   raise notice '%', c;
postgres$# end;
postgres$# $$ language plpgsql;
NOTICE:  Ahoj
DO
postgres=#
```